# Does an oriented graph contain circuits if and only if at least one element of the main diagonal is 1?

Tags: graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

In a course PDF the following proposition is written:

> An oriented graph contains circuits if and only if at least one element of the main diagonal is 1.

I thought of an example that contradicts this proposition:

[image: simple graph example]

How can the quoted proposition be true?

**Update:** Is the proposition about the connections matrix and not about the adjacency matrix as I thought first?

Comment: To they really say circuits? Not maybe *loops*?

Comment: It is a course written in the Romanian language. I just translated this proposition. I thing your translation is correct.

Comment: A loop is and edge connecting a vertex to itself so it corresponds naturally to an entry on the diagonal.

Comment: Then the proposition is about a circuit and I think that it talks about the main diagonal of the connections matrix, not of the adjacency matrix.